# Is there any tip for removing oil from hair without hair washing?

Tags: cleaning, personal-care, hair

I use a oil for hair. Sometimes don't having time or any other reason I can't wash my hair immediately. Is there any way or tip for removing oil from hair without hair washing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boar/natural bristle hairbrushes are very good at distributing oils in your hair. If the oil is concentrated in one spot (your scalp, for example), brush from your scalp to ends to distribute the oils more evenly. You can also use one of these brushes in combination with dry shampoo or powders to absorb some of the oil.

Answer (score 1):

Baking Soda! It is a great for absorbing moisture and odors! ## I use it for SO MUCH! I keep some in a Small Spray Bottle Mixed with a little distilled water and use it as a dry shampoo for both my Pets and Myself if my hair feels greasy and I don't have time to deal with a Shower or bathing them. Depending on your hair color, you can also lightly sprinkle it into your roots. It draws out oils and moisture and absorbs any odors! Great for my White Dogs!

I hope that helps! I use Baking Soda for SOOOOO MUCH!

Comment: I did not try this, but it sounds cool :) I might try it sometime, when I remember.

Answer (score 0):

There are special dry powder hair shampoos which you put on hair and comb it out or just leave it, depending on the product.

Comment: Yes - dry shampoos are the way to go - they are readily found in pharmacies, like Rite Aid and CVS, etc. And they work well, too!

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, you can rub corn meal into your hair, which will absorb the oil, and then brush it out.

50 years ago there was a product called PSSSST that was touted as a dry shampoo spray; spray it on and brush it out. It might have used a corn product to absorb the oil.